# Currency symbol not appearing for lightning data table currency type field in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, sort, currencytype

I have lightning data table with one of the columns associated to Amount field. I want amount values to appear with '$' symbol for which I declared Amount column with type 'Currency' but I was not able to see amount values with '$' or any other currency symbol. As a workaround, I converted the data type of Amount to String and concatenated the '$' symbol :

Column Declaration :
const columns = [{ fieldName: "Amount", hideDefaultActions: true, label: "AMOUNT", type: "String", sortable: "true" }];

Evaluation of Amount value :
rowData.Amount = "$" + (((obj.amount / 100) + '').indexOf('.') == -1 ? (obj.amount / 100) + '.00' : (obj.amount / 100));

But with this workaround, sorting on Amount field is not working as expected. I am using following code for sorting :
[image]

Lightning Datatable html part :

[image]

I need both sorting and display of amount values with currency symbol to be working correctly. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: it will be "currency"  not "Currency"  JS in case sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use currency with small 'c' as the datatype, you would get the symbol.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now